# Java Chronounits Months: exactly one month, greater or less

Tags: java

I need to check if two dates cover exactly one full calendar month, e.g

```
2022-06-01 to 2022-06-30
2022-06-02 to 2022-06-30
2022-06-01 to 2022-07-01
2022-06-15 to 2022-07-15
```

The first is exactly one month, the second less, the third more and the last as well since it's more than one calendar month.

Using the Java

```
Chronounits.Months.between(date1,date2)
```

has the disadvantage that I cannot check if it's exactly one month. I check if it's more or less, but how to check if two dates exactly one full calendar month? And have as well less than one month covered or if it's in two different months?

Comment: You could start with the first date, add one month, subtract one day, then compare it to the second date.

Comment: But this would miss the sample 4 - since it's more than one full calendar month. I would get with this a false positive.

Comment: I don't think you would.

Comment: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72985521/java-chronounits-months-exactly-one-month-greater-or-less#comment128908901_72985521) proposed by Dawood is working (or I misunderstood the question), see https://ideone.com/iyEcUj (almost a one-liner, note I added one additional test case) - can also be done to show less, equal or more than a month: https://ideone.com/Awyajg

Comment: Yeah, I should have written it as an answer, not a comment.  Kind of short of time though.

Comment: Thx for the effort. I was looking for a solution which covers exactly a full calendar month.  If the dates are not within the same month ==> not covered either. Therefore I accepted the answer since it meets my needs.

Comment: Yeah, because it's more or less two calendar months. Think about fiscal contributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `firstDayOfMonth` and `lastDayOfMonth` temporal adjusters to adjust the start and end dates. If they cover exactly one month, then adjusting the start date to the end of the month should equal the end date, and adjusting the end date to the start of month should equal the start date. (assuming start date is always before end date)

For the other two cases, we can simply check if the year and month components are the same. If they are, then it covers less than a month, otherwise it is more than a month.

```
private static MonthCoveringResult numberOfMonthsCovered(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
    if (start.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()).equals(end) &&
            end.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()).equals(start)) {
        return MonthCoveringResult.EXACTLY_ONE;
    } else {
        var startYM = YearMonth.from(start);
        var endYM = YearMonth.from(end);
        return startYM.equals(endYM) ? MonthCoveringResult.LESS_THAN_ONE : MonthCoveringResult.MORE_THAN_ONE;
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution is exactly what I was looking for. Thx.